# Getting NSRangeException with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject

Hello you helpfull guys,

I have the following problem and try to solve for hours.
It feels like somethings wrong with my CoreData/FetchResultsController whatever.

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SavedActivitiesViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil



override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActivityCell") as! ActivityCell

    let activity = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    self.configureCell(cell, withObject: activity)


    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let activityView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ActivityView") as! ActivityViewController
    let activityViewNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: activityView)

    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    appDelegate.drawerContainer!.centerViewController = activityViewNav
    appDelegate.drawerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(DrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 80.0
}



func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {

    let activity = object as! Activity
    let cell = cell as! ActivityCell

    cell.shortTitle.text = activity.valueForKey("shortTitle") as? String

}

// MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Activity", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "activityID", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
    case .Move:
        tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

For some reason my App will crash when it starts:

2016-08-04 16:47:29.546 TestApp[2527:852314] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'
*** First throw call stack:

...

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

---

if I enabled breakpoints for all exceptions it breaks on:

```
let activity = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
```

in tableView Method with cellForRowAtIndexPath

---

When I print the `self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count` it says `1` but shouldn't it print `0` when I don't save anything? (I deleted the App on the Simulator, so my CoreData should be deleted)

Also when I set the return of

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count ?? 0
}`

to 0 my App is running. If I now save an object into my coreData via App I can set the return back to `return self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count ?? 0`
and it starts again. But I can only save this one Object.
I get the following message:

---

2016-08-04 17:14:40.407 TestApp[2582:984402] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:1502
2016-08-04 17:14:40.408 TestApp[2582:984402] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 10 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)

---

The row 10 comes from multiple clicking on save button.
I don't know what I am done wrong, I worked with a book that explained coreData and compared it with examples from the internet.

You guys are my last hope.

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049312/pfbatchfaultingarray-objectatindex

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that.

Comment: I don't think my code is wrong or something like that, I used the same snippets in other projects without any problems. I think something with my CoreData is wrong, I read about deleting cache or something, maybe something like that?

Comment: Try deleting your store file

Comment: Whats that and how can I do that?

Comment: OMG its so embarrassing! I twisted the return of the numberOfSectionsInTableView and numberOfRowsInSection Methods SORRY

Comment: So you mean you are showing a cell in each section not the rows in a single section.

Comment: I override my numberOfSectionsInTableView Method always to return 1 and the Method that should return the numberOfObject in a section returns number of sections in my fetchedResultsController, really stupid. Everything works fine now